# HTML 5 Div Position

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="first">Something</div>
<div id="last">something too</div>

<style>
     #last {
          position: absolute;
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
          bottom:0; /*yes this div is at the bottom*/
     }
     #first {

     }
</style>
```

My problem is that I can't reach last div with the border of the first div. 
I want last div to be at bottom and first div to have overflow:auto;? But it doesn't work. 
When I fill my div some text nothing is showing no scrollbar or anything like that and the first div kind of goes behind the last div even though I haven't assigned them any z-index values. 


How Can I solve this? I want my first div to grow until it reaches last div and fill it with text maybe with scrolling appearing when it is only needed. I mean when two divs touch each other kind of.

Comment: You should be able to rework this for a fixed footer:
http://codepen.io/parkerbennett/pen/hbzJm

It's unfortunately not super straightforward, but it's doable. Probably easier with Javascript + CSS.

Comment: Actually, then again I think there might be a simpler solution... I'll take a shot at it...

Comment: Thank you for your response @HamzaKubba . I will check it out and wait for another possible answers too.

Comment: So you want the top `div` to full up all the screen vertically except for the bottom `div`. Do you want the bottom `div` to be fixed height or a `%`?

Comment: `position: absolute;` removes elements from the normal document flow and places them above other non `z-index` elements on the z plane. That is why it appears to be overlapping your first element.

Comment: Yes I want to accomplish that.  I want my first div to grow until last div and then overflow to appear.

Comment: Do you want it to touch the bottom one if their isn't enough text to make it that height?

Comment: But, what's the other way of placing div at the bottom?

Comment: No I want it touch last one if there's enough of more text in the first div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6MR4T/ Will do what you mentioned here. Bottom is fixed, top grows until it touches and then stops growing but gets a scroll bar. Uses no JS, only CSS. However, in question comments you seem to have changed your mind and want it to touch at all times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a fixed size footer (`#last`) but the content (`#first`) expands as needed:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 200px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#first {
    background-color: #5588FF;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#last {
    background-color: #FF8855;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

See this fiddle for the full solution: http://jsfiddle.net/xWa9f/4/

Comment: This doesn't work, because the OP only wants the top container (blue) to touch the bottom one if there is a large enough amount of text. This touches at all times.

Comment: I interpret his words differently... he said this: "I want my first div to grow until it reaches last div", which sounds like the opposite of what you just said.

Comment: Anyway, if that's the issue, he just needs to remove the `height: 100%;` from the style for `#first`.

Comment: Check the comments. I asked for clarification. "Do you want it to touch the bottom one if their isn't enough text to make it that height?" - "No I want it touch last one if there's enough of more text in the first div." The original question wasn't clearly stated.

Comment: Ahh, I'll update the fiddle... those comments happened after I wrote my response. EDIT: updated... removed the `height: 100%` as explained.

Comment: Yes I did want it. I think approach with javascript is the one.

Comment: ideaot... sigh, use http://jsfiddle.net/xWa9f/2/ if you want `#first` to touch `#last` always, and http://jsfiddle.net/xWa9f/3/ if you want it to only touch if it is full. The JS solution is incomplete. (see my comment there, or just try resizing the window with that solution).

Comment: But wait second link doesn't happen to solve it I think. O.O because it doesn't even scroll even though there is some text behind of last div.

Comment: ideaot: You're right... fixed in my answer, and jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xWa9f/4/ (it needed `max-height: 100%` on `#first`)

Comment: But can't the first div stay in it's position and grow only when the enough text is added and grow until it reaches second div?

Comment: That's what happens for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/xWa9f/4/
(try removing some text or making the running part of the fiddle bigger). What is the problem?

Comment: Hamza, that /4 is great! I assumed that he'd have to use calc() to achieve the not always touching version, but this removes that need. +1!

Comment: This actually works. Thanks. I wanted to achieve this and at first sight I think there was some kind of problem maybe with my browser. I checked this out http://jsfiddle.net/xWa9f/4 and thank you. This works I guess.

Answer (score 1):

if you accept some javascript in the mix, i have this solution for you.
first, change the `absolute` positioning to `fixed` positioning of the `#last` div.
set `overflow:auto` to the `#first` div and the javascript does the rest (you need jQuery):

```
(function () {


    var heights = window.innerHeight;
    var outerHeights = $("#last").outerHeight(true);
    jQuery('#first').css('height', (heights - outerHeights) + "px");

})();
```

basically it calculates the window height of your monitor, it subtracts the height of the `#last` div and gives what's left to the `#first` div. when the content exceeds the available pixel height, a scroll bar will appear.

check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/vlrprbttst/rR7Uu/2/

the plus here is this works at any window resolution, so you don't have to worry about screen resolutions and you don't have to worry about the height of your `#last` div (margins, paddings, borders, whatever included)

Comment: You would need to listen to the window `resize` (or `onresize`) event and call this function again when it is triggered, so this is missing some code...

Comment: I can see that link is not working. I'll give it a try.

Comment: ideaot, you mentioned in comments on OP that you don't want the boxes to touch when there isn't a large amount of text, but here they appear to touch at all times.

Comment: @AndyM what i understood is that the two divs needed to always touch and eventually have an overflow with a scroll when the content exceeded the available space. and this is what it does.

Comment: @HamzaKubba do you know how to add that to my javascript?

Comment: OP explicitly said that wasn't the case in the comments. However, it seems he changed his mind. ~shrug~ I don't know.

Comment: Agreed AndyM. vlr, yes I do, but I think a pure CSS solution is better in this case so I feel like it would be leading to a worse answer than the one I already gave. If you want to look it up though, see: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/emw2x/2/

```
 body, html{
        height: 100%;
    }  

#last {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    bottom:0; /*yes this div is at the bottom*/
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
     }

#first {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
     }
```

Give that a try to see if that's what you want.

Comment: I was gonna say, why so harsh AndyM... then I realized his name is actually ideaot. :)

Comment: it stays at the bottom just fine for me, regardless of how much text is in the top div. http://jsfiddle.net/emw2x/5/

Comment: Hmmm, I must have been looking at an older version? My apologies! However, it still doesn't meet the OP's requirements of not touching at all times. Boxes should only touch when there is enough text, and these boxes touch at all times.