# Force a container to fill the residual space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The div container `.wrapper` under `#Wrapper` must fill the space between header and footer. So it should get the height of the #Wrapper container.

[jsFiddle Example - UPDATE](http://jsfiddle.net/4q3pC/11/)

Could you help me?

Comment: could this be useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639798/html-5-div-position/23640151#23640151

Comment: Hi, I've also thought about using jquery. I came along with a similar solution http://jsfiddle.net/5d9R7/. Works fine as long as you don't reduce the size of the window. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way, because your header and footer have specific heights, is to do the following:

```
// Add the following to #wrapper

#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 200px;    
  // IMPORTANT
  // REMOVE the following rule:
  // min-height: 100%;      
}
```

Remember to remove the `min-height: 100%;` from `#wrapper`

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4q3pC/1/). Good luck...

Comment: the footer has not a specific height. only min-height. That's the problem here. also top 200px won't work because (sry i forgot to say this) there will be a navigation bar with a adaptive height.